# Status Code for an endpoint that creates but returns no data

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I have and endpoint from a REST API that creates an entity, but the endpoint does not return any data.

Would it be ok to return a `201` status code? or it would be better to return a `204` status code?

Which one wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `201` status code means that a resource has been created. The `204` status code is not suitable for this situation.

A response for a request that creates a resource should have the `201` status code and the `Location` HTTP header with a URI that identifies the newly created entity. Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> [**6.3.2.  201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being  created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI. [...]